# How to search for a function/class within a module?

Tags: python, module, dir

I want to know if a function/class exists somewhere in a module.
I do know how to generate a list of all the classes/functions that are at the upper level/hierarchy of the module using `dir()`
For example, let's say I want to know if function `now()` exists inside the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
dir(datetime)
```

But this does not list the function `now()` because `now()` is contained in a deeper level (in `datetime.datetime` to be exact). How do I check if `now()` exists or not?
Or maybe there is a way to list everything from all the levels?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code lists the contents of modules recursively. Note however it will fail if two submodules/objects/... share the same name

```
import time
import datetime

pool=[] # to avoid loops 

def recdir(d,n=''):
    children_all=dir(d)
    children=[c for c in children_all if c[0]!='_' and not c in pool]
    for child in children:
        pool.append(child)
        full_name=n+"."+child
        print "Found: ","'"+full_name+"' type=",eval("type("+full_name+")")
        string="recdir(d."+child+",'"+full_name+"')"
        print "Evaluating :",string
        time.sleep(0.2)
        eval(string)

recdir(datetime,'datetime')
```

Comment: So, recdir takes two arguments, the module name, and the object you want to search for. If I put "timedelta" (class within the datetime module) as second argument, I get an error telling me that "timedelta" is not defined.